# Как внести в .gitignore все файлы с папки "web", кроме папки "web/sites"?

Tags: git, gitignore

Как внести в .gitignore все файлы с папки "web", кроме папки "web/sites"?

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять фабулу самого вопроса только в теле либо дополнить её какими-то данными — вопрос с одинаковым описанием и названием выглядит не слишком хорошо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54870120/5479247

Comment: я понимаю, но честно что-то лучше описывающее вопрос не нашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На будущее: вот [описание работы](https://tyapk.ru/blog/post/gitignore) .gitignore и его команды.

```
/web/*
!/web/sites/
```

Answer (score 1):

В документации есть пример для вашей ситуации https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_examples

```
/web/*
!/web/sites
```